# Writing Bubble Sort using Foldl or Foldr in SML

Tags: sorting, functional-programming, sml, bubble-sort, smlnj

Is there a way to implement bubble sort using the Foldl or Foldr methods available in SML? Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: I believe you can. Doing it with foldl will probably require you to reverse the order of the list every time you traverse it, so you'll have to keep track of the direction it's in so you can reverse it one last time if necessary.

Comment: The state that you carry along in your "carry value" will have to keep track of both the accumulated sorted elements and a flag marking whether you've changed the list on this pass. (And, as mentioned, possibly whether the list is reversed on this pass.)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an implementation in OCaml to demonstrate the technique to my own satisfaction.

I broke the sort process into two parts. One is a compare-and-swap function that is called via fold_left (foldl). This function has the type (with the bool being whether a swap has occurred in this scan):

```
bool * 'a list -> 'a -> bool * 'a list
```

Each time it runs it does a swap if appropriate, building up a new list in its result that is composed in reverse order from the input. (This is necessary because of foldl's left-to-right, tail-recursive behavior.) It also keeps track of whether any swaps were made in this scan of the list (necessary so we know when to stop sorting).

The other function is recursive and simply keeps invoking the scan until no change is made. This function also has a boolean that it toggles on each call to keep track of whether the list is currently reversed. When it sees that no swap was made in the latest scan, then it returns the resulting list. If the list is currently reversed then it reverses it one last time before returning it.

This is the type of the second function (with the bool here being whether the list is currently reversed):

```
bool -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

It should be equally possible to write a bubble sort that uses foldr. It won't be tail-recursive (because foldr is not), and since it scans the list from right-to-left, you won't have to deal with the reversing issue that you have with foldl.

Comment: So pretty much you are writing two functions, one that keeps track of whether a swap has occurred and also swaps, and another one to invoke that swap and a boolean to see if a swap has occured. If no swap occurs then the list is returned.

Also are you sure that `Foldl` goes left to right, it seemed like from the documentation it went right to left, while `Foldr` went left to right. This could just be my mistake of analyzing it. Here is the: [List Structure SML Reference](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldr:VAL)

Comment: @Rootkit32: I guess it depends on your definition of "left to right". What I'm sure of is that foldl processes the head of the list before the tail. Foldr processes the tail first, then back toward the head. In reality I have three functions: there's a "master" function that takes just a list as an argument and all it does is call function #2 in my answer with the appropriate starting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer your question, but hopefully this will help:

```
fun bsort [] = []
|   bsort [x] = [x]
|   bsort (x::y::xs) =   
                    if(y<x) then
                        y::bsort(x::xs)
                    else
                        x::bsort(y::xs);

fun bubblesort [] = []
|   bubblesort (x::xs) = bsort(x::(bubblesort(xs)));
```

Remember, we have to do the bubble sort till the list is completely sorted.